# Vertical response api in grails

Tags: spring, api, grails, groovy, httpbuilder

I'm trying to use Vertical response api in my grails project. But it giving following error

**CODE:**

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder()

http.request('https://vrapi.verticalresponse.com/',GET, TEXT) { req ->
    uri.path =  'api/v1/contacts?type=basic'
    headers.'Authorization' = 'Bearer api_token'
    headers.'Content-Type'='application/json'


    print('====================================')
    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        assert resp.status == 200
        println "My response handler got response: ${resp.statusLine}"
        println "Response length: ${resp.headers.'Content-Length'}"
        reader // print response reader
    }

    // called only for a 404 (not found) status code:
    response.'404' = { resp ->
        println 'Not found'
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Unauthorized. Stacktrace follows:
groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:652)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:508)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:417)
    ...
```

Comment: You're sending `api_token` literally, is that correct?

Comment: Might be you are sending wrong api token(or X-Auth-Token)in headers.'Authorization'. Have you tried it by using [Rest Client Builder Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder). It makes calling REST calls very easy.

Comment: Passing token is valid  , I have tested it using postman extension of chrome and it's working without any problem

Comment: It's working after moved to `HttpClient` , I think problem is with httpbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `HttpClient` instead of `HTTPBuilder` it working without any problem. So I think the problem is with `HTTPBuilder`

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet('http://vrapi.verticalresponse.com/api/v1/contacts?type=basic');

// add request header
request.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer token")

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

print("Response Code : "
        + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode())

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));


render rd.readLines()
```